# What data type should I use for a 'duration' attribute?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, sqldatatypes

I'm using phpmyadmin/MySQL to make a database.

It's for a plane/bus/train booking system.

I have a 'depart_time' attribute which is a time data type. In the same table I have a 'duration' attribute. Later on I will need to do multiplication on this duration attribute (depending on if it is train/bus/plane).

**My question is** - what would be the best data type for this duration attribute?

I thought about using a decimal type - but then the values in it won't represent the time exactly (e.g. 1.30 won't represent 1 and a half hrs, it would need to be 1.50 - if that makes sense).
I also thought about using the time data type for this field as well, but I wasn't sure if multiplication would be possible on that?

I couldn't find any help after googling about multiplication on the time data type.

Hopefully this made sense, if you need anymore information then feel free to ask in the comments!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what will be multiplied with duration value ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html

Comment: @UsmanRana numbers like 2,3,4 etc

Answer (score 6):

Use an `int` and record durations in the smallest unit you're interested in. For example, if you need minute accuracy, store one and a half hours as 90 minutes. Formatting that value for display purposes is presentation logic, not the business of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in that position I would probably either:

1. In seconds. Unlikely that you need more precision than that.
2. In a string such as `P1D`  for 1 day and `P1W2DT3H` for 1 week, 2 days, 3 hours. This is a standard format used by many libraries and deals better with situations where something really takes 1 day, but it's a day with a leap hour.

For most cases just using seconds will be fine though.

Answer (score 0):

I would represent it in the database as seconds or minutes (minimum precision you want). Showing it to the user should be done dynamically in frontend (e.g. in minutes (1 min, 30 min 180min), hours (0.1h, 1h, 3h, 3.0h), days (0.5d, 1d) or minimal packed (1d 5h 42min).

You should keep this separate. So I suggest to use seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved how I'm going to do this.

Instead of doing it within the database. I am going to do the multiplication using Python.

I took the information from the table, turned the data into int/datetime.deltatime and the multiplication worked.

I then just needed to return that data depending on whether it's bus/train/plane.

Answer (score 0):

For a multiplier not involved with money, simply use `FLOAT`.

Then work in seconds (or minutes if you prefer).  That can be in `INT UNSIGNED`.

Use appropriate `DATETIME` functions to convert seconds to `hh:mm` or whatever output you desire.  Note:  The internal format need not be the same as the display format.

Answer (score 0):

A duration could be represented in an open standard manner using ISO 8601 duration format.

See https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm